# Kotlin: Platform declaration clash

Tags: kotlin

Код:

```
abstract class Figure {
var color: Color? = null
abstract fun setColor(color: Color)
abstract fun getColor(): Color?
abstract fun perimeter(): Double
abstract fun area(): Double}
```

Достал меня уже уже "declaration clash" error. Где там ошибка понятия не имею. До компиляции всё зелёное, а после компиляции выводит ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот код класса Circle:

```
class Circle(private val center: Point, private val radius: Double) : Figure() {
override fun setColor(color: Color) {
    this.color = color
}

override fun getColor(): Color? {
    return color
}

override fun perimeter(): Double {
    val PI = 3.141592
    val P = 2 * PI * radius
    return P
}
}
```

Comment: Стоило бы немного теории изучить, тогда и практика "доставать" ошибками перестанет :) Как альтернатива ответу ниже: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-field/

Answer (score 2):

**Уберите set/get функции**, они и так генерируется при создании переменной

```
var color: Color? = null
```

*Вот эти две функции Вам не нужны.*

```
   abstract fun setColor(color: Color)

   abstract fun getColor(): Color?
```

Вы создаете публичную переменную и дополнительно к ней пишете сет и гет (В kotlin'e этого делать не нужно), которые уже и так есть.

```
Circle(...).color = newColor // set
Circlt(...).color // get
```

Answer (score 0):

```
enum class Color {
RED, GREEN, BLUE
```

}

```
abstract class Figure {
abstract var color: Color?
abstract fun setColor(color: Color)
abstract fun getColor(): Color?
abstract fun perimeter(): Double
abstract fun area(): Double
```

}

```
class Circle(private val center: Point, private val radius: Double) : Figure() {
override var color: Color? = null

override fun setColor(color: Color) {
    this.color = color
}

override fun getColor(): Color? {
    return color
}

override fun perimeter(): Double {
    val PI = 3.141592
    val P = 2 * PI * radius
    return P
}
```

}

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Код выглядит вполне функциональным, но для улучшения его читаемости и точности можно внести несколько изменений:

```kotlin
import kotlin.math.PI

abstract class Figure {
    var color: Color? = null

    abstract fun setColor(color: Color)
    abstract fun getColor(): Color?
    abstract fun perimeter(): Double
    abstract fun area(): Double
}

class Circle(private val center: Point, private val radius: Double) : Figure() {
    override fun setColor(color: Color) {
        this.color = color
    }

    override fun getColor(): Color? {
        return color
    }

    override fun perimeter(): Double {
        return 2 * PI * radius
    }

    override fun area(): Double {
        return PI * radius * radius
    }
}
```

Внес изменения:

1. Импортировал константу `PI` из `kotlin.math`.
2. Добавил пробелы для улучшения читаемости кода.
3. Добавил метод `area()` в класс `Circle`, чтобы удовлетворить абстрактное требование базового класса `Figure`.